# Read in Dollar Amount (with dollar sign) C++

Tags: c++, input, user-input

I need to read in a value (cin) including a dollar sign and a dollar amount, but I only want to read in the amount.

In other words, I have this input:
    "$3458.5,"
but I want to read in and store
    "3458.5"

The current approach I thought of was reading the value in as a string, removing the first character, and then converting to a double. But, I feel like this method is inefficient and there's a better method out there. Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like a small inefficiency that you should not worry about :)

Comment: I try to stay away from C++ locale stuff because I find it overly complex and intrusive and even non-portable due to lack of implementation support, but there *is* [`std::money_get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/money_get) and associated machinery. As I recall P.J.Plauger wrote a series of articles about how to use it. Might be worth googling up -- or not, IDK. An example of non-portability is the use of an UTF-8 locale in the example code for the docs I linked to over at cppreference.com. That won't work with Visual C++, where it's documented that UTF-8 locales are not supported.

Comment: As an aside: Floating point variables and currency don't get on very well together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Magnus: this seems minor. But if you really want to do it, just read a character then read a double:

```
char ch;
double d;
std::cin >> ch >> d;
```

Comment: I thought of doing that, but I thought it would try to read in the entire string as a char somehow which would make it invalid. Does it not matter that there isn't whitespace between the $ and the amount?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(stream.peek() == '$') stream.get();
stream >> amount;
```

Comment: I probably won't need the check since the input is promised to be well-formatted, but that would work, thanks!

Comment: good answer. If you also make the **if(stream.peek()=='$')** to a **while(stream.peek()=='$')** it will ensure to discard any number of '$' from the stream before reading the number.

Comment: Let's make it real hard! `for(char c = stream.peek(); !(c == '-' || c == '.' || std::isdigit(c)); c = stream.peek()) stream.get();`

Answer (score 1):

If you use `scanf` instead of `cin`, you can drop the `$` if you know it will always be there and write the information directly to a float.

```
float d;
scanf("$%f", d);
```

Answer (score 1):

C++98/03 had a `money_get` facet to do things like this. Unfortunately, using it was fairly painful (to put it nicely).

C++11 added a `get_money` manipulator to make life quite a bit simpler. It works something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    long double amt;

    std::cin.imbue(std::locale(""));
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));

    std::cin >> std::get_money(amt);
    std::cout << std::showbase << std::put_money(amt) << "\n";
}
```

Now, there are a couple of things to be aware of here. First and foremost, the conversion from the external to internal representation isn't specified, but in the implementations I've seen, `$3458.5` will *not* be read as `3458.5`--it'd be read and stored as `345850` -- that is, a count of the number of pennies.

When you use `put_money` to write the data back out, however, it'll be converted symmetrically with whatever was done during input, so if you entered `$3458.5`, it'll be written back out the same way.

There is one other caveat: I've seen at least one implementation that was strangely finicky about input format, so it required either 0 or 2 digits after the decimal point during input, so either `$3458.50` or `$3458` would read fine, but `$3458.5` wouldn't be read at all (it'd be treated as a failed conversion).

Comment: Gotcha, I think I'm going to stick with one of the first couple solutions, but it's good to know something like this exists! Thanks!